# Sage WordPress - Plugin Namespace: Not Found

Tags: plugins, themes, theme-roots, namespace

I originally posted in the Sage forum [here](https://discourse.roots.io/t/sage-gutenberg-and-acf-blocks/13945/32?u=darthink).

I'm trying to get a plugin to work but it's not, and I feel like it's a very general *Namespace* problem, and not something with the actual plugin, so I feel I could find success here.

The plugin (and it's code/repo) is here: https://github.com/ItinerisLtd/acf-gutenblocks

Any ideas how I can solve this error?

```
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'Itineris\AcfGutenblocks\Plugin' not found in /app/public/wp-content/plugins/acf-gutenblocks/acf-gutenblocks.php:32
Stack trace:
#0 /app/public/wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php(286): Itineris\AcfGutenblocks\{closure}('')
#1 /app/public/wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php(310): WP_Hook-&gt;apply_filters('', Array)
#2 /app/public/wp-includes/plugin.php(465): WP_Hook-&gt;do_action(Array)
#3 /app/public/wp-content/plugins/advanced-custom-fields-pro/acf.php(334): do_action('acf/init')
#4 /app/public/wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php(286): ACF-&gt;init('')
#5 /app/public/wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php(310): WP_Hook-&gt;apply_filters(NULL, Array)
#6 /app/public/wp-includes/plugin.php(465): WP_Hook-&gt;do_action(Array)
#7 /app/public/wp-settings.php(525): do_action('init')
#8 /app/public/wp-config.php(76): require_once('/app/public/wp-...')
#9 /app/public/wp-load.php(37): require_once('/app/public/wp-...')
#10 /app/public/wp-blog-header.php(13): require_once('/app/public/wp-...')
#11 /app/public/index.php(17): require('/app in /app/public/wp-content/plugins/acf-gutenblocks/acf-gutenblocks.php on line 32
```

I put the following code into my `setup.php`:

```
add_filter('acf_gutenblocks/blocks', function (array $blocks): array {
    $new_blocks = [
        Testimonial::class,
    ];
    return array_merge($blocks, $new_blocks);
});
```

If I remove the code above, my application works correctly.

My file structure, where `app` lives in `wp-content/themes/[themename]/app`:

```
app
-- Blocks
-- -- Testimonial
-- -- -- views
-- -- -- -- frontend.php
-- -- -- Testimonial.php
-- setup.php
```

In my setup.php I have the following code:

---

**[Link to Gist with *my current* code here](https://gist.github.com/darthink/10fd1b70007d0847b6469ae545415f66)**
**(setup.php, Testimonial.php, Frontend.php)**

---

You'll notice also I put `protected function registerFields(): array {}` into the bottom of `Testimonial.php`, I hope that's a normal place to put it.

For the setup namespace, I've tried different variations: 
`use Blocks\Testimonial\Testimonial;`
`use app\blocks\testimonial\testimonial;` (with lower case filenames also)

**Edit** 
The best idea I've got so far is that I've installed the plugin ( `composer require itinerisltd/acf-gutenblocks` ) to the directory `sitename/app/public/wp-content/plugins/` and maybe the files in the Sage theme aren't picking up the namespace because it's in the main WordPress plugins.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You must specify in the roots sage theme `composer.json` the runtime where autoload can find the classes.

```
  "autoload": {
    "psr-4": {
      "App\\": "app/",
      "App\\Blocks\\": "app/Blocks/",
      "Itineris\\AcfGutenblocks\\": "../../plugins/acf-gutenblocks/src/",      
    }
  }
```

Don't forget to run `composer dump-autoload`

Comment: Thanks for the answer! For record purposes, I didn't test this as I had found an alternate solution, but it logically makes sense.